# Como borrar informacion de un div y cargar otra en react

Tags: jquery, laravel, reactjs

Como puedo hacer esto de jQuery: `$('#div').empty().html(data);` , pero en react?

Comment: Podrías agregar una demostración de que sos parte del esfuerzo por pasar eso a react por favor? Lecturas recomendadas: [como preguntar?](/help/how-to-ask) y [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar dangerouslySetInnerHTML

```
const App = () => {
  const data = 'lorem <b>ipsum</b>';

  return (
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data}}
    />
  );
}

export default App;
```